# Problem with bridged mode in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, kali-linux, virtualbox, nat

I installed Kali Linux in my Windows 10 in VirtualBox and 
I use bridge network setting in network settings to give it the same IP address than my home router.
But today it is not connecting to network to my college Wi-Fi. 
When I change settings to NAT then network works in Kali Linux from my college Wi-Fi router but does not work in bridged adapter settings.

Answer (score 2):

When you are in bridged mode all the packet coming back to your Kali Linux IP
are eaten by your Windows 10 host since they are targeted to its IP address.
They don't arrive to the VirtualBox virtual interface. You can understand
this by checking the IP addresses of your Windows 10 and your Kali Linux.

You can workaround this problem by turning your VirtualBox network interface in
promiscuous mode where it will deal with all packets (and not only the
broadcasted ones).

But the correct way to access the Internet from your Kali Linux is through
a Nat network configuration so that your VirtualBox will play the role of a
router between your Windows 10 and your Kali Linux.